# JavaScript Scroll Function when image changed

Tags: javascript

I'm facing a problem with my scroll function, this function was theoretically run when the user scrolls the scroll.

When scrolling, the image was supposed to be changed, but nothing happens, the console.log test message appears on the console outside the scroll function, the console.log message does not appear inside the function and the scroll function does not execute when scrolling scroll, I'm running in laravel, what mistake did I make when writing the code and how to make it work please?

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var imagemElement = document.getElementById('imagemextra');
  var novaImagem = "{{asset('assets/img/logo.png')}}"
  var imagemInicial = "{{asset('assets/img/bg-black2.png')}}"

  window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    console.log('oi');
    if (window.scrollY >= 10) {
        imagemElement.src = novaImagem;
    } else if (window.scrollY < 2){
        imagemElement.src = imagemInicial;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body{height:200vh;}
```

```html
<img id="imagemextra" src="{{asset('assets/img/bg-black2.png')}}" alt="BackGround">
```

Comment: Rather than running things "on dom content loaded", load your script with `<script src="...." async defer></script>`: by definition your script will now run only once the page is ready for DOM queries, so that'll simplify your code. Also, stop using `var`, it's the ancient variable keyword. Use the modern `let` or `const` depending on whether a variable should be reassignable or not.

Comment: I've edited your question so the code can be run as a snippet. I think the problem is that `{{asset('assets/img/bg-black2.png')}}` is not a valid path to an image. Your code works, but you have to provide a valid URL.  the `{{ ... }}` syntax looks like it's from some kind of templating system, which will not be parsed here

Comment: Estou usando dentro de <script> no final do body mas por algum motivo não funciona ao rolar o scroll, em relação a parar de utilizar var, obrigado pela dica já fiz a substituição do var.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can only read/speak English.  StackOverflow is meant to be an English only site.

Comment: Sorry, I say I'm using it inside <script> at the end of the body but for some reason it doesn't work when scrolling, in relation to stop using var, thanks for the tip, I've already replaced the var.

Answer (score 0):

Another problem might be that you're attempting to use a scroll on a page that doesn't have a scrollbar. However, the scroll might be present within the same block where the picture is displayed. Here's an example where scrolling doesn't work in the first version, but it does work in the second one. To solve this issue, you need to attach an event not to the window, but to the selector of the desired block.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    function startScroll(suffix){
    const imagemElement = document.getElementById('imagemextra'+suffix);
    const novaImagem = "https://via.placeholder.com/50/000000/FFFFFF/?text=IMG_1:.*";
    const imagemInicial = "https://via.placeholder.com/50/FF0000/FFFFFF/?text=IMG_2:.*";
    const wrapperElement = document.getElementById('wrapper'+suffix);

    wrapperElement.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
      console.log('oi');
      if (window.scrollY >= 10) {
        imagemElement.src = novaImagem;
      } else if (window.scrollY < 2) {
        imagemElement.src = imagemInicial;
      }
    });
  }
  startScroll(1);
  startScroll(2);
});
```

```css
#imagemextra {
  position:fixed;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 120px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px black;
}
#wrapper2 {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
#imagemextra1,
#imagemextra2 {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper1" class="wrapper">
  <img id="imagemextra1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50/000000/FFFFFF/?text=IMG_1:.*" alt="BackGround">
</div>

<div id="wrapper2" class="wrapper">
  <img id="imagemextra2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50/000000/FFFFFF/?text=IMG_1:.*" alt="BackGround">
  <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
  <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
  <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
</div>
```

Comment: The image urls still have {{ and }}, doesn't matter what else you do, the URL is invalid

Comment: I have replaced the resource links. In my message above, I wanted to draw attention to the OP on a different issue. If there is no scroll on the page, but there is a scroll within the block, then the event will not trigger.

Comment: the keys {{}} is because the images are in the public folder in laravel that's why I use them, I added the spaces inside the div where the img is, but it didn't work, and even with the spaces in my view I could be wrong because not I still understand, but in my view, the spaces do not make sense since there is no scroll just for the image div, the site scrolls as a whole.